# How to determine duplicates in list of strings in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I'm wondering how to determine the duplicates in the following and populate a new list of strings with the duplicates?

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
```

I was thinking along these lines, but gets a compile error saying I can't apply the - operators to List of strings.

```
List<string> namesCollisions = test - test.Distinct().ToList();
```

So I tried the following as suggested and the list is empty even though PROGRAM3 is listed twice???

[image]

Comment: @amit you are right, i updated

Comment: Why are you trying to subtract the duplicates from the original list? You don't say what you're trying to do here. IEnumerable<T>.Distinct() is all you need, for what you've said you want. What is the subtraction for? Please edit your question to explain.

Answer (score 7):

## Benchmarks

- I benchmarked 4 algorithms
- In 64bit`on both`.Net Framework 4.7.1`
- Each test is run 1000 times and average
- I scaled each dataset.
- Before each test the framework does a `GC.Collect` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers`
- and 1 isolated test to verify the results

I used 4 lots of input data

**Input**

```
public static List<string> ListofSimpleString(int scale)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(0, scale)
                  .Select(x => Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(y => (char)_rand.Next(255)).ToString())
                  .ToList();
}
public static List<string> ListofSimpleString2(int scale)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(0, scale)
                  .Select(x => Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(y => (char)_rand.Next(48,95)).ToString())
                  .ToList();
}
public static List<string> ListofSimpleString4(int scale)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(0, scale)
                  .Select(x => _rand.Next(10).ToString())
                  .ToList();
}
public static List<string> ListofSimpleString5(int scale)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(0, scale)
                 .Select(x => "duplicate value")
                 .ToList();
}
```

## Results

```
Mode             : Release (64Bit)
Test Framework   : .NET Framework 4.7.1

Operating System : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version          : 10.0.17134

CPU Name         : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Description      : Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7

Cores (Threads)  : 4 (8)      : Architecture  : x64
Clock Speed      : 3401 MHz   : Bus Speed     : 100 MHz
L2Cache          : 1 MB       : L3Cache       : 8 MB

Benchmarks Runs : Inputs (4) * Scales (5) * Benchmarks (4) * Runs (10) = 800
```

**Test 1**

```
--- 10 Random ascii chars -----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Value          |       Average |       Fastest |         Cycles |    Garbage | Test |    Gain |
--- Scale 10,000 ----------------------------------------------------------------- Time 0.099 ---
| Dictionary     |      1.298 ms |      1.040 ms |      4,180,070 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 43.71 % |
| GroupByCount   |      1.315 ms |      1.128 ms |      4,473,950 | 264.242 KB | N/A  | 42.98 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |      1.387 ms |      1.097 ms |      4,622,163 | 264.242 KB | N/A  | 39.88 % |
| HashSet        |      2.306 ms |      2.010 ms |      7,842,618 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 100,000 ---------------------------------------------------------------- Time 0.656 ---
| Dictionary     |     11.599 ms |     11.090 ms |     39,514,786 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 48.72 % |
| GroupByCount   |     12.469 ms |     12.172 ms |     42,491,474 |   2.008 MB | N/A  | 44.88 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |     12.834 ms |     12.490 ms |     43,703,545 |   2.008 MB | N/A  | 43.26 % |
| HashSet        |     22.620 ms |     22.171 ms |     77,091,768 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 1,000,000 -------------------------------------------------------------- Time 6.502 ---
| Dictionary     |    116.635 ms |    114.583 ms |    397,153,297 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 50.92 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |    130.604 ms |    128.622 ms |    444,500,775 |  16.008 MB | N/A  | 45.04 % |
| GroupByCount   |    133.642 ms |    128.416 ms |    455,399,304 |  16.008 MB | N/A  | 43.76 % |
| HashSet        |    237.646 ms |    231.029 ms |    809,489,660 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 10,000,000 ------------------------------------------------------------- Time 5.844 ---
| Dictionary     |  1,169.275 ms |  1,163.115 ms |  3,984,243,078 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 50.76 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |  1,353.768 ms |  1,345.292 ms |  4,608,323,709 | 256.009 MB | N/A  | 43.00 % |
| GroupByCount   |  1,358.509 ms |  1,344.632 ms |  4,627,402,507 | 256.009 MB | N/A  | 42.80 % |
| HashSet        |  2,374.831 ms |  2,334.440 ms |  8,089,227,303 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 100,000,000 ------------------------------------------------------------ Time 8.679 ---
| Dictionary     | 11,751.858 ms | 11,656.590 ms | 40,027,059,699 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 52.24 % |
| GroupBySkipAny | 13,585.036 ms | 13,346.376 ms | 46,230,547,515 |   2.000 GB | N/A  | 44.79 % |
| GroupByCount   | 13,891.448 ms | 13,664.273 ms | 47,215,273,015 |   2.000 GB | N/A  | 43.54 % |
| HashSet        | 24,605.782 ms | 24,440.468 ms | 83,658,042,598 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Test 2**

```
--- 10 Random printable ascii chars -------------------------------------------------------------
| Value          |       Average |       Fastest |         Cycles |    Garbage | Test |    Gain |
--- Scale 10,000 ----------------------------------------------------------------- Time 0.259 ---
| Dictionary     |      1.087 ms |      1.052 ms |      3,654,669 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 50.38 % |
| GroupByCount   |      1.182 ms |      1.133 ms |      4,020,552 | 264.211 KB | N/A  | 46.07 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |      1.300 ms |      1.163 ms |      4,415,126 | 264.211 KB | N/A  | 40.67 % |
| HashSet        |      2.191 ms |      2.024 ms |      7,462,586 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 100,000 ---------------------------------------------------------------- Time 0.758 ---
| Dictionary     |     12.033 ms |     11.333 ms |     40,839,598 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 48.66 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |     12.821 ms |     12.616 ms |     43,599,424 |   2.008 MB | N/A  | 45.30 % |
| GroupByCount   |     12.903 ms |     12.643 ms |     43,879,671 |   2.008 MB | N/A  | 44.95 % |
| HashSet        |     23.438 ms |     22.309 ms |     79,514,592 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 1,000,000 -------------------------------------------------------------- Time 6.687 ---
| Dictionary     |    119.383 ms |    116.696 ms |    406,335,788 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 51.02 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |    134.819 ms |    131.747 ms |    458,589,071 |  16.008 MB | N/A  | 44.68 % |
| GroupByCount   |    139.834 ms |    132.961 ms |    476,092,342 |  16.008 MB | N/A  | 42.63 % |
| HashSet        |    243.722 ms |    239.580 ms |    829,409,546 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 10,000,000 ------------------------------------------------------------- Time 8.579 ---
| Dictionary     |  1,237.373 ms |  1,213.387 ms |  4,203,352,967 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 49.48 % |
| GroupByCount   |  1,404.209 ms |  1,385.300 ms |  4,778,762,566 | 256.009 MB | N/A  | 42.67 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |  1,423.058 ms |  1,384.701 ms |  4,838,714,809 | 256.009 MB | N/A  | 41.90 % |
| HashSet        |  2,449.190 ms |  2,381.713 ms |  8,334,623,472 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 100,000,000 ----------------------------------------------------------- Time 59.573 ---
| Dictionary     | 12,126.807 ms | 11,692.415 ms | 41,233,771,464 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 49.00 % |
| GroupByCount   | 13,289.256 ms | 13,062.683 ms | 45,292,203,200 |   2.000 GB | N/A  | 44.12 % |
| GroupBySkipAny | 13,760.635 ms | 13,261.366 ms | 46,825,002,767 |   2.000 GB | N/A  | 42.13 % |
| HashSet        | 23,780.270 ms | 22,785.622 ms | 80,971,187,805 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Test 3**

```
--- Random number between 0 and 10 ------------------------------------------------------------
| Value          |      Average |      Fastest |         Cycles |    Garbage | Test |    Gain |
--- Scale 10,000 --------------------------------------------------------------- Time 0.224 ---
| Dictionary     |     0.397 ms |     0.387 ms |      1,349,447 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 50.59 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |     0.495 ms |     0.490 ms |      1,683,949 | 200.563 KB | N/A  | 38.38 % |
| GroupByCount   |     0.506 ms |     0.503 ms |      1,722,584 | 200.563 KB | N/A  | 36.97 % |
| HashSet        |     0.803 ms |     0.786 ms |      2,734,083 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 100,000 -------------------------------------------------------------- Time 0.459 ---
| Dictionary     |     3.929 ms |     3.767 ms |     13,387,884 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 48.65 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |     5.195 ms |     4.873 ms |     17,699,816 |   2.510 MB | N/A  | 32.09 % |
| GroupByCount   |     5.233 ms |     4.904 ms |     17,825,215 |   2.510 MB | N/A  | 31.60 % |
| HashSet        |     7.650 ms |     7.444 ms |     26,081,151 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 1,000,000 ------------------------------------------------------------ Time 3.416 ---
| Dictionary     |    39.934 ms |    38.031 ms |    136,107,565 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 47.61 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |    52.159 ms |    50.011 ms |    177,797,622 |  20.011 MB | N/A  | 31.57 % |
| GroupByCount   |    54.562 ms |    49.745 ms |    185,883,905 |  20.011 MB | N/A  | 28.42 % |
| HashSet        |    76.221 ms |    73.899 ms |    259,702,109 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 10,000,000 ---------------------------------------------------------- Time 33.643 ---
| Dictionary     |   396.948 ms |   381.873 ms |  1,352,809,995 |   7.035 KB | N/A  | 47.82 % |
| GroupByCount   |   519.931 ms |   515.210 ms |  1,771,927,979 | 160.012 MB | N/A  | 31.66 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |   537.953 ms |   516.127 ms |  1,833,424,578 | 160.013 MB | N/A  | 29.29 % |
| HashSet        |   760.781 ms |   751.582 ms |  2,592,592,185 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 100,000,000 --------------------------------------------------------- Time 43.701 ---
| Dictionary     | 3,945.544 ms | 3,845.146 ms | 13,442,361,467 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 49.08 % |
| GroupByCount   | 5,666.408 ms | 5,501.203 ms | 19,301,260,141 |   2.500 GB | N/A  | 26.87 % |
| GroupBySkipAny | 5,688.156 ms | 5,536.729 ms | 19,370,101,611 |   2.500 GB | N/A  | 26.59 % |
| HashSet        | 7,748.656 ms | 7,605.495 ms | 26,399,373,179 |   7.315 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Test 4**

```
--- All Duplicates ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Value          |      Average |      Fastest |         Cycles |    Garbage | Test |    Gain |
--- Scale 10,000 --------------------------------------------------------------- Time 0.957 ---
| Dictionary     |     0.444 ms |     0.425 ms |      1,508,780 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 50.55 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |     0.561 ms |     0.543 ms |      1,912,069 | 264.211 KB | N/A  | 37.44 % |
| GroupByCount   |     0.566 ms |     0.544 ms |      1,927,506 | 264.211 KB | N/A  | 36.93 % |
| HashSet        |     0.897 ms |     0.876 ms |      3,058,602 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 100,000 -------------------------------------------------------------- Time 0.341 ---
| Dictionary     |     4.342 ms |     4.195 ms |     14,764,603 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 56.79 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |     6.090 ms |     5.437 ms |     20,636,444 |   2.008 MB | N/A  | 39.38 % |
| GroupByCount   |     6.327 ms |     5.812 ms |     21,478,886 |   2.008 MB | N/A  | 37.03 % |
| HashSet        |    10.047 ms |     8.627 ms |     34,243,915 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 1,000,000 ------------------------------------------------------------ Time 2.962 ---
| Dictionary     |    45.242 ms |    42.814 ms |    154,054,415 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 54.02 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |    58.574 ms |    53.289 ms |    199,411,629 |  16.008 MB | N/A  | 40.47 % |
| GroupByCount   |    63.450 ms |    54.705 ms |    215,792,787 |  16.008 MB | N/A  | 35.52 % |
| HashSet        |    98.396 ms |    85.450 ms |    335,093,581 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 10,000,000 ---------------------------------------------------------- Time 28.309 ---
| Dictionary     |   432.955 ms |   424.321 ms |  1,474,860,339 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 49.97 % |
| GroupByCount   |   600.265 ms |   581.515 ms |  2,044,282,844 | 256.009 MB | N/A  | 30.64 % |
| GroupBySkipAny |   603.112 ms |   581.099 ms |  2,054,976,446 | 256.009 MB | N/A  | 30.31 % |
| HashSet        |   865.449 ms |   854.386 ms |  2,949,024,388 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 100,000,000 --------------------------------------------------------- Time 38.508 ---
| Dictionary     | 4,394.937 ms | 4,261.656 ms | 14,973,292,181 |   8.000 KB | N/A  | 50.11 % |
| GroupBySkipAny | 5,799.055 ms | 5,718.249 ms | 19,758,314,574 |   2.000 GB | N/A  | 34.16 % |
| GroupByCount   | 5,909.234 ms | 5,781.676 ms | 20,126,526,198 |   2.000 GB | N/A  | 32.91 % |
| HashSet        | 8,808.441 ms | 8,617.298 ms | 30,010,947,763 |   8.000 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## The algorithms were

**Dictionary**

```
public class Dictionary : Benchmark<List<string>, List<string>>
{

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetDistinctDuplicates(IEnumerable<string> original)
    {
       var dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
       foreach (var s in original)
          if (dict.TryGetValue(s, out var isReturnedDupl))
          {
             if (isReturnedDupl)
                continue;

             dict[s] = true;
             yield return s;
          }
          else
             dict.Add(s, false);
    }
    protected override List<string> InternalRun()
    {
       return GetDistinctDuplicates(Input).ToList();
    }

}
```

**GroupByCount**

```
public class GroupBy : Benchmark<List<string>, List<string>>
{
   protected override List<string> InternalRun()
   {
      return Input.GroupBy(x => x)
                  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                  .Select(y => y.Key)
                  .ToList();
   }
}
```

**GroupBySkipAny** Enigmativity

```
public class GroupBy2 : Benchmark<List<string>, List<string>>
{
   protected override List<string> InternalRun()
   {
      return Input.GroupBy(x => x)
                  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                  .Select(y => y.Key)
                  .ToList();
   }
}
```

## Summary

`Dictionary` is the fastest, `GroupBy` always does well, *Enigmativitys* version with `Skip` and `Any` is slightly faster, and for some reason `Hashset` always is about 35-50 percent slower. However things are a lot less certain at the smaller scales. With the results shown and even in cycles and the test data given it seems pretty clear, though i have a feeling there might be more at play since other answers benchmarks are getting different results.

Anyway have fun finding duplicates

Comment: @galakt Basically as above, however this is my own benchmark lib and not public yet, however if you want to do your own benchmarking you can use https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet its a great tool to have

Comment: I mean no just result, but a bench methods code also looks better

Comment: I did it via BenchmarkDotNet and got opposite result

Comment: Make sure you run in release

Comment: @galakt also note im doing GetDuplicates(Input).Distinct().ToList(); to get a unique list of duplicates as would groupby, so it makes sense its slower as it has to iterate the list twice

Comment: I did it as GetDuplicates(input).Distinct().ToList() (you can look at source). Also there is no second list iteration. GetDuplicates returns IEnumerable, so it near equal to only (+1 Set collection, +1 "if(Add())" operation) from Distinct

Comment: All good. for a list of 100 to 100000, groupby won in all my benchmarks in release 64bit for random strings of 10 characters with 100 tests each and a Gc before every run. When I have time tomorrow I'll test it against benchmark. Net on the same data and set up because I'm morbidly interested

Comment: `Why doesn't it work with Except though?` Because `Except` deals with `Distinct` so it _effectively_ calls `Distinct` on the two input enumerables.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the results if you changed `.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)` to `.Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())`

Comment: @Enigmativity updated, yeah nice trick, squeezed a little more performance out of the groupby

Comment: @TheGeneral - The code based on my comment in your answer is still showing `g.Count() > 1`.

Comment: @TheGeneral - The other thing that would be interesting is to record the results in a `Dictionary<int, List<TimeSpan>>` with the key being the number of 1st gen GC's that ran during the test and to ignore all runs where a 2nd or high gen ran. I find that the GC's really message with the timing results.

Comment: @Enigmativity ill run the tests again, i think i muddled up this post, the any is faster though.. i think i see what your saying in regards to GC. however before each test, and each of their runs, it does GC.Collect, and GCWaitForPendingFinalizers. ie each test on each benchmark should be pretty clean as far as garbage goes. however later today ill do a debug output of my benchmarker to output whats managed and in what generation just to make sure. as i use this pretty heavily at work

Comment: @TheGeneral - You might be surprised how many GC's get performed during the tests even though you're doing a `GC.Collect()` first. And if a higher gen collection occurs then the slow down can be enormous.

Comment: @Enigmativity I added MemoryDiagnoser in benchmark result :)

Answer (score 5):

No linq, pure code

Get all duplicates

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetDuplicates(IEnumerable<string> original)
{
    var hs = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (var item in original)
    {
        if (!hs.Add(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Get distinct duplicates

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetDistinctDuplicates(IEnumerable<string> original)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    foreach (var s in original)
    {
        // If found duplicate 
        if (dict.TryGetValue(s, out var isReturnedDupl))
        {
            // If already returned
            if (isReturnedDupl)
            {
                continue;
            }

            dict[s] = true;
            yield return s;
        }
        else 
        {
            // First meet
            dict.Add(s, false);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**: Add bench

**Update2**: Update bench source, bench results

**Update3**: add MemoryDiagnoser to bench and other algorithms

**Difference between [TheGeneral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612975/thegeneral) bench and mine**

```
           |          TheGeneral |               My bench |
---------- |-------------------- |----------------------- |
 Used tool |   Own benchmark lib |        BenchmarkDotNet |
 Input     | Random string cases |           Corner cases |
```

*Algorithms*

- HashSet (GetDuplicates)
- Dict (GetDistinctDuplicates)
- GroupBy ([TheGeneral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612975/thegeneral) method)
- GroupByWithSkip ([Enigmativity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259769/enigmativity) method)

Did benchmark with [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) with Default config

*Input*

- **AllDupl** - Corner case when collection contains only same string
- **NoDupl** - Corner case when collection contains only uniq strings

*Ini*:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.14, OS=Windows 10.0.17134
Intel Core i7-4710HQ CPU 2.50GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
  [Host]     : .NET Framework 4.6.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.7.3101.0
  DefaultJob : .NET Framework 4.6.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.7.3101.0
```

*Legends*

```
  input       : Value of the 'input' parameter
  description : Value of the 'description' parameter
  Mean        : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error       : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev      : Standard deviation of all measurements
  Gen 0       : GC Generation 0 collects per 1k Operations
  Gen 1       : GC Generation 1 collects per 1k Operations
  Gen 2       : GC Generation 2 collects per 1k Operations
  Allocated   : Allocated memory per single operation (managed only, inclusive, 1KB = 1024B)
  1 us        : 1 Microsecond (0.000001 sec)
```

*Result*

```
          Method |         input |               description |         Mean |       Error |      StdDev |     Gen 0 |     Gen 1 |    Gen 2 |  Allocated |
---------------- |-------------- |-------------------------- |-------------:|------------:|------------:|----------:|----------:|---------:|-----------:|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         GroupBy |   Array[1000] |       AllDupl, Count=1000 |     43.62 us |   0.6882 us |   0.5747 us |    2.6855 |         - |        - |     8606 B |
 GroupByWithSkip |   Array[1000] |       AllDupl, Count=1000 |     42.86 us |   0.3188 us |   0.2826 us |    2.7466 |         - |        - |     8669 B |
         HashSet |   Array[1000] |       AllDupl, Count=1000 |     72.54 us |   0.3339 us |   0.3124 us |    0.1221 |         - |        - |      429 B |
            Dict |   Array[1000] |       AllDupl, Count=1000 |     35.44 us |   0.1953 us |   0.1731 us |    0.0610 |         - |        - |      244 B |

         GroupBy |   Array[1000] |        NoDupl, Count=1000 |    110.13 us |   0.2874 us |   0.2548 us |   17.8223 |         - |        - |    56408 B |
 GroupByWithSkip |   Array[1000] |        NoDupl, Count=1000 |    153.37 us |   0.6419 us |   0.5690 us |   38.0859 |         - |        - |   120411 B |
         HashSet |   Array[1000] |        NoDupl, Count=1000 |     49.50 us |   0.1833 us |   0.1715 us |   18.4937 |         - |        - |    58672 B |
            Dict |   Array[1000] |        NoDupl, Count=1000 |     71.20 us |   0.1944 us |   0.1723 us |   23.0713 |         - |        - |    73027 B |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
         GroupBy |  Array[10000] |      AllDupl, Count=10000 |    431.36 us |   1.8869 us |   1.7650 us |   41.5039 |         - |        - |   131580 B |
 GroupByWithSkip |  Array[10000] |      AllDupl, Count=10000 |    431.19 us |   1.3593 us |   1.2050 us |   41.5039 |         - |        - |   131680 B |
         HashSet |  Array[10000] |      AllDupl, Count=10000 |    721.68 us |   2.0894 us |   1.7448 us |         - |         - |        - |      432 B |
            Dict |  Array[10000] |      AllDupl, Count=10000 |    357.74 us |   1.3790 us |   1.2899 us |         - |         - |        - |      248 B |

         GroupBy |  Array[10000] |       NoDupl, Count=10000 |  1,316.20 us |   8.2301 us |   7.6984 us |  119.1406 |   29.2969 |        - |   611337 B |
 GroupByWithSkip |  Array[10000] |       NoDupl, Count=10000 |  1,908.77 us |  15.7756 us |  14.7565 us |  203.1250 |   97.6563 |        - |  1251339 B |
         HashSet |  Array[10000] |       NoDupl, Count=10000 |    696.26 us |   0.9738 us |   0.6441 us |   94.7266 |   94.7266 |  94.7266 |   538736 B |
            Dict |  Array[10000] |       NoDupl, Count=10000 |    954.53 us |   1.9645 us |   1.8376 us |  124.0234 |  124.0234 | 124.0234 |   673164 B |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
         GroupBy | Array[100000] |     AllDupl, Count=100000 |  4,767.00 us |  17.4749 us |  16.3461 us |  281.2500 |  281.2500 | 281.2500 |  1051088 B |
 GroupByWithSkip | Array[100000] |     AllDupl, Count=100000 |  4,742.72 us |  22.8393 us |  21.3639 us |  281.2500 |  281.2500 | 281.2500 |  1051088 B |
         HashSet | Array[100000] |     AllDupl, Count=100000 |  7,247.34 us |  12.4036 us |  11.6023 us |         - |         - |        - |      448 B |
            Dict | Array[100000] |     AllDupl, Count=100000 |  3,557.70 us |  14.2987 us |  11.1635 us |         - |         - |        - |      256 B |

         GroupBy | Array[100000] |      NoDupl, Count=100000 | 31,044.51 us | 371.9730 us | 347.9438 us | 1125.0000 |  750.0000 | 312.5000 |  5849142 B |
 GroupByWithSkip | Array[100000] |      NoDupl, Count=100000 | 42,374.47 us | 306.7762 us | 286.9586 us | 2187.5000 | 1187.5000 | 500.0000 | 12249704 B |
         HashSet | Array[100000] |      NoDupl, Count=100000 |  7,497.73 us |  54.6210 us |  51.0925 us |  656.2500 |  593.7500 | 593.7500 |  4830548 B |
            Dict | Array[100000] |      NoDupl, Count=100000 |  9,825.25 us |  51.1668 us |  45.3581 us | 1062.5000 |  984.3750 | 984.3750 |  6042773 B |
```

**Summary**

Performance of *GroupBy*, *HashSet* and *Dict* heavily depends on input. If input contains only duplicates - *Dictionary* better. But when input contains only uniq values - *HashSet* better. With random input (like in TheGeneral code) *GroupBy* works better than *HashSet*. Also note that input with only unique values - really worst case for *GroupBy* with huge perf hit.

Allocation and GC really interesting columns in result...

So what is better heavily depends on count of duplicates in input, input total count and your goals

*Source*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var conf = ManualConfig.Create(DefaultConfig.Instance);
        conf.Add(MemoryDiagnoser.Default);
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<DuplicateFindBench>(conf);
    }
}

public class DuplicateFindBench
{
    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Data))]
    public List<string> GroupBy(string[] input, string description)
    {
        return input.GroupBy(x => x)
                            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                            .Select(y => y.Key)
                            .ToList();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Data))]
    public List<string> GroupByWithSkip(string[] input, string description)
    {
        return input.GroupBy(x => x)
            .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())
            .Select(y => y.Key)
            .ToList();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Data))]
    public List<string> HashSet(string[] input, string description)
    {
        return GetDuplicates(input).Distinct().ToList();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Data))]
    public List<string> Dict(string[] input, string description)
    {
        return GetDistinctDuplicates(input).ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetDuplicates(IEnumerable<string> original)
    {
        var hs = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var item in original)
        {
            if (!hs.Add(item))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetDistinctDuplicates(IEnumerable<string> original)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        foreach (var s in original)
        {
            // If found duplicate 
            if (dict.TryGetValue(s, out var isReturnedDupl))
            {
                // If already returned
                if (isReturnedDupl)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                dict[s] = true;
                yield return s;
            }
            else 
            {
                // First meet
                dict.Add(s, false);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object[]> Data()
    {
        const int count1 = 1000;
        yield return new object[] { ArrayParam<string>.ForPrimitives(CreateNoDuplInput(count1).ToArray()), $"NoDupl, Count={count1}" };
        yield return new object[] { ArrayParam<string>.ForPrimitives(CreateAllDuplInput(count1).ToArray()), $"AllDupl, Count={count1}" };

        const int count2 = 10_000;
        yield return new object[] { ArrayParam<string>.ForPrimitives(CreateNoDuplInput(count2).ToArray()), $"NoDupl, Count={count2}" };
        yield return new object[] { ArrayParam<string>.ForPrimitives(CreateAllDuplInput(count2).ToArray()), $"AllDupl, Count={count2}" };

        const int count3 = 100_000;
        yield return new object[] { ArrayParam<string>.ForPrimitives(CreateNoDuplInput(count3).ToArray()), $"NoDupl, Count={count3}" };
        yield return new object[] { ArrayParam<string>.ForPrimitives(CreateAllDuplInput(count3).ToArray()), $"AllDupl, Count={count3}" };
    }

    public List<string> CreateNoDuplInput(int inputSize)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++)
        {
            result.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        return result;
    }
    public List<string> CreateAllDuplInput(int inputSize)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++)
        {
            result.Add("duplicate value");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The results have never made sense, the only way i can get hashset to be fastest in any environment is with a limited data set https://dotnetfiddle.net/eqGjlg, what do you get if you just run the .net fiddle code on your pc ? sorry i was fiddling around with the code, anyway

Comment: @TheGeneral Looks like you totally ignore main point :) (depending on diversity of input set) Check this little changed fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/3YgUYC

Answer (score 2):

In linq or SQL you must use `EXCEPT` instead of minus like below:

```
var namesCollisions = test.Except(test.Distinct().ToList());
```

but I cant understand what you want in result and this answer always return empty list.

Comment: It compiles fine, but with 2 duplicates in the list namesCollisions is empty...it doesn't seem like it is working @hasangholamali

Comment: Could you put your data and the result you want to get what you want?

Comment: I added the debug info to the original question.  Please notice 2x PROGRAM3 and the dump is empty.  @hasan gholamali

Comment: sorry your question is not clear for me, I think you want to subtract two lists and the answer is for this

Comment: This will always yield an empty enumeration, because it is like saying "i want all numbers from one to ten except all distinct numbers from one to ten".

Comment: @Streamline yes you are true, as I said I show subtract two list is done by `EXCEPT` and is not minus because the image and the result he wants is not clear to me

Comment: If you want to provide an empty list (which is all this does) then `new List<string>()` would be much simpler...